# can we set tabindex for textbox and other controls in javascript

Tags: javascript, textinput

can we set tabindex for input and other html controls using javascript. I've seen this in .net. can we do the same in javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set tabindex for <strike>`input`</strike> all html-elements, in javascript:

```
[someElement].tabIndex = [number]
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("id").tabIndex=3`  (any number I have used 3 for example and put the id of the element at the place of id)